# Enforcing std::shared_ptr usage via protected constructors and a static member function to create instances and std::make_shared

Tags: c++, std, shared-ptr, make-shared

I have some classes that are only ever used via `std::shared_ptr`. Instances of these classes are not designed to be used directly by allocating them on the stack or by raw pointers via `new`. I enforce this currently by making the constructors `protected` and having a `static` member function that actually does object instantiation and returns a `shared_ptr` to the object:

```
class Example {
protected:
    Example() { }
public:
    static std:shared_ptr<Example> create() { return std::shared_ptr<Example>(new Example()); }
};
```

I realize this isn't bullet proof, as you can still call `get()` on the `shared_ptr`, but it seems reasonable as an indication of support usage.

However, I can't use `std::make_shared()` as the constructor is `protected`, and I know there are memory allocation/performance advantages to `make_shared()`.

Is the above bad practice, or is there a way of using `make_shared()` without making the constructors `public`?

Comment: This is questionable design. Why class is designed in such a way that it forces it's user to allocate it through some specific facility?

Comment: Could you explain why `Instances of these classes are not designed to be used directly by allocating them on the stack or by raw pointers via new`? This might help to give you a solution to what you try to achieve/solve.

Comment: @remy that is sadly a C++11 answer, and C++17 changes best practices since then.

Answer (score 1):

There is on old trick to give limited permission to another function to make an object; you pass a token.

```
struct Example_shared_only {
private:
  // permission token.  explicit constructor ensures
  // you have to name the type before you can create one,
  // and only Example_shared_only members and friends can
  // name it:
  struct permission_token_t {
    explicit permission_token_t(int) {}
  };
public:
  // public ctor that requires special permission:
  Example_shared_only( permission_token_t ) {}
  // delete special member functions:
  Example_shared_only()=delete;
  Example_shared_only(Example_shared_only const&)=delete;
  Example_shared_only(Example_shared_only &&)=delete;
  Example_shared_only& operator=(Example_shared_only const&)=delete;
  Example_shared_only& operator=(Example_shared_only &&)=delete;
  // factory function:
  static std::shared_ptr<Example_shared_only>
  make_shared() {
    return std::make_shared<Example_shared_only>( permission_token_t(0) );
  }
};
```

now `Example_shared_only::make_shared()` returns a `shared_ptr` that was created with `make_shared`, and nobody else can do much with it.

If you have access to more modern dialects of C++ we can do better than that:

```
template<class F>
struct magic_factory {
  F f;
  operator std::invoke_result_t<F const&>() const { return f(); }
};

struct Example2 {
  static std::shared_ptr<Example2> make() {
    return std::make_shared<Example2>( magic_factory{ []{ return Example2{}; } } );
  }
private:
  Example2() = default;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a418e65d4272501c).

This requires [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) for guaranteed elision.

`magic_factory` can be cast into whatever your factory function produces, and with guaranteed elision builds that object in-place.  It has fancier uses in other contexts, but here it lets you export the constructor to make shared.

The lambda passed to `magic_factory` is an implicit friend of `Example2`, which gives it access to the private ctor.  Guaranteed elision means a function with the signature `()->T` can be called to create a `T` "in place" without any logical copies.

`make_shared<T>` attempts to construct its `T` using the argument.  C++ examines `operator T` while this happens; our `magic_factory` has one such `operator T`.  So it is used.

It does something like

```
::new( (void*)ptr_to_storage ) Example2( magic_factory{ lambda_code } )
```

(If you are unfamiliar, this is known as "placement new" -- it states "please build an `Example2` object at the location pointed to by `ptr_to_storage`).

The beauty of guaranteed elision basically passes into the `lambda_code` the address where the `Example2` is being created (aka `ptr_to_storage`), and the object is constructed right there.